# Is translation a good idea to implement horizontal scrolling?

Tags: angular, translation, transformation, horizontal-scrolling

I have to implement horizontal scrolling in my angular 2 app where I have to scroll by fixed number of pixels. The scrollbar should not be visible and user will use the left and right buttons for scrolling.

I am wondering, is using transform property to implement scrolling a good idea? Specially if I have to make it work on all browsers.

I will have to query window.getComputedStyle() to fetch the current transform value and then apply translation.

Comment: you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use normal scrolling instead of transform. You are still able to hide the scrollbars and enable scrolling through your buttons.
Just get your scrollable container with ViewChild and access the nativeElements scroll attributes.

yourFile.ts

```
@ViewChild('scrollElement') scrollableContainer: ElementRef;

onScroll(value){
   this.scrollableContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft =
              this.scrollableContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft + value;
}
```

yourFile.html

```
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div #scrollElement class="scrollableContainer">
   <!-- yourScrollableContent -->
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="onScroll(-10)" label="left"></button>
<button (click)="onScroll(+10)" label="right"></button>
```

yourFile.css

```
.outerContainer{
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
}
.scrollableContainer{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```